# Nativescript - The app cannot be installed on the simulator

Tags: ios, nativescript

The ios simulator stopped working with the following error. Whats happening?

> Installing on device 8E7C6AE0-A3AB-476E-B9D9-931F3738EF3A... Unable to
> apply changes on device: 8E7C6AE0-A3AB-476E-B9D9-931F3738EF3A. Error
> is: Command xcrun with arguments simctl install
> 8E7C6AE0-A3AB-476E-B9D9-931F3738EF3A
> /Users/username/Documents/Work/ns-mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator/nsmobile.app
> failed with exit code 5. Error output:  An error was encountered
> processing the command (domain=IXErrorDomain, code=5):
>
> A coordinated
> app install already exists for au.com.companyname.nsmobile with
> intent IXCoordinatorIntentUpdating (creator InstallCoordination Simple
> SPI) but request by CoreSimulatorBridge (pid 2878) was for intent
> IXCoordinatorIntentInitiating

Comment: Have you tried changing the simulator?

Comment: Try resetting the Simulator and run the app again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings